# React flexbox works with inline styles but not with css file

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, frontend

I'm trying to style my react frontend for a project, and want the Form and Display components to be next to each other in a flex container. It works when I do an inline style as below, but has no effect when I use the App.css file. Could somebody explain this to me? Here is the project: https://github.com/GeorgeCGarman/tip-calculator-react

```
    <div className="container" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Form />
        <Display />
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS syntax in App.css is incorrect, but you're on the right track.

Instead of:

```css
.selectTip {
  display: "flex";
  flex-direction: "column";
}

.container {
  display: "flex";
}

.Form {
  display: "flex";
}
```

You need to remove the quote marks:

```css
.selectTip {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.Form {
  display: flex;
}
```

CSS uses keywords, meaning they do not require quotes, but in React, it must be given as a string (or for things like padding, it may be given as a number)

CSS can be a minefield, so make sure you check out some kind of [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/defaulT.asp)